# generate report with different testname

Tags: python, python-2.7

I'm generating a report with 7 headers and according values with test name being a first value to a pdf file.I have hard coded a test name as 'report1'.Below is my code

```
testname = "report1"
try:
     report(testname,arg2,arg3,arg4,arg5,arg6,arg7)
except Exception:
     print "Error during reporting.Check the input parameters"

def report(self,testname,arg2,arg3,arg4,arg5,arg6,arg7):
    for name in self.testname:
        "report runs here"
```

Report looks like below

```
TestName Cvalue  RValue  Lower  Higher  Measured   Result
report1  1500    50      100    10000   845        pass
```

I need to run the application again to get the second report with test name as 'report2'. I have to change testname such that on every run testname has to increment the number by one and display 'report2'. Please suggest!

Comment: Do you want report1, report2, report3 etc.?

Comment: @alexanderlukanin13 i just want to put a testname in a loop and change it's name everytime when i run it.

Answer (score 0):

You need to store "next report number" somewhere, to make it persistent between script runs.

The simple-and-stupid way is to scan your reports directory every time and pick next report name according to maximum existing report.

For example, if you already have:

```
my_reports/
    report1
    report2
```

next name should be `report3`.

A simple code snippet to do it:

```
import os
import re

def get_next_report_name(report_dir):
    """Returns next report file name."""
    max_number = 0
    for file_name in os.listdir(report_dir):
        match = re.match(r'^report(\d+)$', file_name)
        if match:
            max_number = max(max_number, int(match.group(1)))
    return 'report{0}'.format(max_number + 1)

report_dir = 'INSERT YOUR REPORT DIR HERE'
testname = get_next_report_name(report_dir)
```

Note that this algorithm is **not scalable**, because the more files you have, the more time it will take to find next number. For real-life use, you should invent something more efficient.

Comment: report2,report3 is not the separate files. It is just another testname with diffrent values.somethiing looks like this

Answer (score 0):

For achieving this feature, you'll have to store `current_report_number` somewhere. You may use python `pickle` module for persisting `current_report_number`.

You may refer this code segment.

```
import pickle


try:
    report_id = pickle.load(open("config.dat"))
except IOError:
    #First run, config file does n't exist
    report_id = 0
report_id += 1
print report_id


# REPORT GEN START

# REPORT GEN END

#persist current report id
pickle.dump(report_id, open("config.dat", "w"))
```